# Prevent the use of ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()

Tags: c++, windows, security, named-pipes

When a named pipe client connects to a server and writes some data, the server can call [`ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to impersonate the client.  (The server does need to read the data before calling `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient()`).

As we can see at [this link](http://www.blakewatts.com/namedpipepaper.html), this can lead to a privilege escalation security vulnerability.

Is possible to prevent/disable/deny this impersonation, so that a client can connect to the named pipe but not allow the server to impersonate?

**Note 1:** I know that the client needs to write on the named pipe first. But in some cases, the client will need to write first, so I need to prevent this security flaw.

**Note 2:** A solution that applies to Windows XP and above is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling [CreateFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) to open the client end of the named pipe, pass `SECURITY_IDENTIFICATION` in the `dwFlagsAndAttributes` parameter.  This allows the server to identify the user and to determine the client's privileges, but prevents the server from impersonating the client's security context.

You can use `SECURITY_ANONYMOUS` instead if you also want to prevent the server from identifying the user.

Note that the server can still successfully call ImpersonateNamedPipeClient() but any attempt to make use of the impersonation token will be restricted by the specified impersonation level.  For example, if the server attempts to open a file while impersonating the client at identification or anonymous level, the operation will fail.

For more information, see the [Impersonation Levels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378832(v=vs.85).aspx) page on MSDN.

It should also be noted that as of Windows XP service pack 2, the server cannot impersonate the client unless it holds the SeImpersonatePrivilege privilege.  (See [ImpersonateNamedPipeClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378618(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN.)  In the default configuration, only system services and administrators have this privilege.  This effectively mitigates many (though not all) of the risks described in the article you link to.

Comment: If you are using C# NamedPipeClientStream use the overload that accepts `System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification` parameter.